# PHP/cUrl Redirection after take link

Tags: php, redirect, curl, page-curl

I have this code and need to help for transfer

```
$curl = new curl();
$curl->cookies('cookies/'.md5($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']).'.txt');
$curl->ssl(0, 2);

$url = "https://exapmle.com/login/";
```

But when script take exaple.com/login has redirected to login.exapmle.com/logon?=Data+Data
how can i make after redirected $url to use new redirected url.

Please help me anyone

Comment: Can you show the curl class code or link to documentation?
I honestly don't know it.

Answer (score 0):

I honestly don't know the curl class, but if it works simillarly to the curl_* functions, you could do the following:

`$curl->setOpt(CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);`

Hope it was helpful.